# Change the type of values in an array according to the types in a Model in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, normalization

I use an API that always returns this type of `array` named `$arrayResponse`:

```
[
  "fooId" => "123",
  "barId" => "456",
  "totoId" => "789",
  "azertyId" => null,
  "closeId" => null
]
```

And, I have this `Model.php` in my code base named `$class`:

```
class Model
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $fooId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $barId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $totoId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $azertyId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $closeId;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFooId(): int
    {
        return $this->fooId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $fooId
     */
    public function setFooId(int $fooId): void
    {
        $this->fooId = $fooId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBarId(): int
    {
        return $this->barId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $barId
     */
    public function setBarId(int $barId): void
    {
        $this->barId = $barId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotoId(): int
    {
        return $this->totoId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $totoId
     */
    public function setTotoId(int $totoId): void
    {
        $this->totoId = $totoId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAzertyId(): int
    {
        return $this->azertyId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $azertyId
     */
    public function setAzertyId(int $azertyId): void
    {
        $this->azertyId = $azertyId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCloseId(): int
    {
        return $this->closeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $closeId
     */
    public function setCloseId(int $closeId): void
    {
        $this->closeId = $closeId;
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to change the attributes of my `Model.php`. It has to stay the same.

After that, I used `symfony/serializer` for:

```
$this->serializer->denormalize($arrayResponse, $class);
```

The problems are:

1. "The type of the "fooId" attribute for class "Folder\Model" must be one of "int" ("string" given)."
2. "The type of the "azertyId" attribute for class "Folder\Model" must be one of "int" ("null" given)."

I don't want to use `AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT` because I want to return the types as they are written in my model.

I tried this before the denormalize call:

```
array_walk($item, function (&$value) {
    if (ctype_digit($value)) {
        $value = (int) $value;
    }
    if (is_null($value)) {
        $value = (int) $value;
    }
    if (is_string($value) && is_numeric($value) && strpos($value, '.')) {
        $value = (float) $value;
    }
});
```

It working but I don't like that because I must use `AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT`.

One solution I have in mind that works would be to manually cast all attributes of `$arrayResponse` to match the Model.

I don't like this solution because I have different `$arrayResponse` and Model, so the solution is long to implement.

I know this solution to get attributes and types for my model https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.reflectionclass.php but it consumes a lot of resources

Would you have any advice for me please?

Comment: You can create some name constructor in your Model class, in example `public static createFromArrayResponse($arrayResponse)` and convert and set values to Model inside it

Comment: Thank's, I solved by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556680/send-a-array-of-custom-normalizer-to-a-main-serializer/75556796#75556796