# Send a array of custom Normalizer to a main Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I have this provider class that contains an array of custom normalizers with the `protected array attribute $normalizers = []`;

```
<?php

namespace Lib\Common\Serializer;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

abstract class NormalizerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $normalizers = [];

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->registerSerializerService();
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    private function registerSerializerService(): void
    {
        $this->app->tag($this->normalizers, 'normalizers');

        $this->app
            ->when(SerializerService::class)
            ->needs('$normalizers')
            ->give(function () {
                return $this->app->tagged('normalizers');
            });
    }
}
```

Here, `$this->normalizers = [FooNormalizer::class, BarNormalizer::class];`.

In my `SerializerService`, I inject on my constructor my `$normalizers` iterable array:

```
class SerializerService implements SerializerInterface, NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface
{
    public const JSON_FORMAT = 'json';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly LoggerInterface $logger,
        private Serializer $serializer,
        private readonly iterable $normalizers
    ) {
        $this->serializer = new Serializer(
            [
                new DateTimeNormalizer(),
                $this->normalizers,
                new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
                new ArrayDenormalizer(),
            ],
            [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(), new JsonDecode())]
        );
    }
```

This configuration does not work because `$this->normalizers` returns an object of type `RewindableGenerator` but, `new Serializer` need a Normalizer component.

If I do this, it's working:

```
    $this->serializer = new Serializer(
        [
            new DateTimeNormalizer(),
            new FooNormalizer(),
            new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
            new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        ],
        [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(), new JsonDecode())]
    );
```

But I need to send a list of custom Normalizers to `SerializerService` without enrolling them directly into the `Serializer` object manually.

I think my NormalizerServiceProvider file is misconfigured.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I solved with:

```
class SerializerService implements SerializerInterface, NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface
{
    public const JSON_FORMAT = 'json';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly LoggerInterface $logger,
        private Serializer $serializer,
        private readonly iterable $normalizers
    ) {

        $this->serializer = new Serializer(
            [
                new DateTimeNormalizer(),
                ...$this->normalizers,
                new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
                new ArrayDenormalizer(),
            ],
            [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(), new JsonDecode())]
        );
    }
}
```